# How can I read file from specific position using Nokia Connectivity API?

Tags: c++, mobile, nokia

I'm using PC Suit Nokia connectivity API (3.2) to gather information about very big files on the phone (about 2GB). To do it, i need to read  file in diffirent parts (usually usefull information in the end of file). I don't want to read whole file, cause it will take to much time.
CONA API presents two function for reading files:

```
DWORD CONAReadFile(FSHANDLE hFSHandle, LPCONAPI_FILE_INFO pFileInfo, unsigned char** ppFileData, DWORD dwLimitedReadSize, const WCHAR* pstrTargetPath);
PCCS_FSAPI CONAReadFileInBlocks(  FSHANDLE hFSHandle, LPCONAPI_FILE_INFO  pFileInfo, DWORD dwOptions, void* pFSBlockDataNotify, DWORD dwFileDataBlockSize, const WCHAR* pstrTargetPath );
```

Both of them provide reading file from the begining. Is there any way to read file from specific position without reading all previous information?

Programming language is C++. Phone connected in PC Suite mode and i can't change it to usb flash drive mode by the condition of the problem (i need to work with application installed on the phone same time).